# Mass replace all values within a table field in phpMyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a site where there are quite a lot of products.

I need to change all stock values within a table field to X (say 100 for example). As it's an online store, all of the stock levels are different as many orders have been made, so I was wondering whether it was possible to mass replace all values within a field within a table to X value.

In the past I've done Search and Replace for a specific value (such as changing all stock with 0 to 100) but I need all different values to be changed.

Is this possible?

Kind regards
Liam

Comment: Do you want the values set to `X` or to a different value for each row?  Sample data and desired results are really helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's simple SQL:

```
UPDATE tablename SET tablefield=X
```

Or did I miss something?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    update 
    table_name
    set x=100
```

x is table field name.